# Hibernate Search - Setting Facets via a Field Bridge

Tags: java, hibernate-search

In Hibernate Search 5.3 the @Facet annotation was introduced and must be used to store a field as a Facet. What I'm wondering is if their is a way to add a field as a facet in a custom field bridge, without using the @Facet annotation.

My use case is that I have a products with categories, and the category tree path is stored as a string like so

```
"0/10/100/1000"
```

I want to be able to get the counts of all products in a category using facets. The count of a category should include the counts of all sub-categories, hence why each product should have a facet for every parent category

So what I'd like to do is something like:

```
public class CategoryPathFacetFieldBridge implements FieldBridge {
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        String[] pathHolder = ((String)value).split("/");
        for (String id : pathHolder) {
            Field fieldForFacet = new Field(name, id, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
            document.add(fieldForFacet);
        }
    }
}
```

I have actually come up with a workaround, but my preferred method would be to use a custom field bridge as above. Does anyone know if this is possible in hibernate search 5.3+ ?

My workaround looks like so:

```
public void setCategoryPath(String categoryPath) {
    this.categoryPath = categoryPath;
    String[] pathHolder = categoryPath.split("/");
    for (String id : pathHolder) {
        this.categoryPathList.add(new CategoryWrap(id));
    }
}

@Transient
@IndexedEmbedded
@OneToMany
public List<CategoryWrap> getCategoryPathList() {
    return this.categoryPathList;
}

class CategoryWrap{

    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    @Facet(encoding = FacetEncodingType.STRING)
    String categoryId;

    public CategoryWrap(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }
}
```